# Why the same javascript can run with runscript command, but not in getEval in RC

Tags: javascript, selenium-rc

```
string str = "var temp = window.document.getElementById('ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_Manager');temp.style.display = 'inline';";
str += "temp.add(new Option('111', '222'));";
str += "temp.nextSibling.childNodes[1].innerHTML = '<I></I><SPAN></SPAN>Edit Manager Contact';";
//selenium.RunScript(str);
selenium.GetEval(str);
```

Track the error log to see, seems `"temp.add(new Option('111', '222'));";` statement is not work under getEval command. the error show:

> "Access to property denied"

Beside context different from these two commands. Why?

Answer (score 2):

`Runscript` runs the script in the same scope, but `GetEval` takes `str` and tries to run it in a different scope. If the issue is with `temp.add` statement, I guess it is because definition of `Option` is not coming in the scope when executed by `GetEval` .

Comment: i try to put the whole str into same scope.But the error is still existing. str=" window.document.getElementById('ctl00_PageContentPlaceHolder_Manager');temp.style.display = 'inline';temp.add(new Option('111', '222'));temp.nextSibling.childNodes[1].innerHTML = '<I></I><SPAN></SPAN>Edit Manager Contact';";

Comment: Try this-  `string str = "var temp = new Option('111', '222');"
selenium.GetEval(str);` and see whether it is working.